# check string value stored in DriveInfo.Name

Tags: c#, .net, string

I am using the example from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo(v=vs.80).aspx

To print drive information to a console window.  I want to check if d.Name contains "T".  If it does, I wan't to run an app.  If it doesn't do nothing. Here is the code I've been trying. (The default code from the above linked example prints to a command window)

**(d.Name.IsLetter(T))** is the part I'm having trouble with.  Can anyone advise?

```
DriveInfo[] allDrives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();

    foreach (DriveInfo d in allDrives)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Drive {0}", d.Name);

         if (d.Name.IsLetter(T))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Run App.");
                notePad.Start();
            }//end if
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Do Nothing.");
            }//end else
        Console.WriteLine("  File type: {0}", d.DriveType);
        if (d.IsReady == true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("  Volume label: {0}", d.VolumeLabel);
            Console.WriteLine("  File system: {0}", d.DriveFormat);
            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Available space to current user:{0, 15} bytes",
                d.AvailableFreeSpace);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total available space:          {0, 15} bytes",
                d.TotalFreeSpace);

            Console.WriteLine(
                "  Total size of drive:            {0, 15} bytes ",
                d.TotalSize);
        }//end if
    }//end for

}//end main
```

Comment: For future reference, this question has _nothing_ to do with DriveInfo and 98% of the code is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `d.Name.Contains("T")`

There is a `Char.IsLetter()` method, but that only checks whether the argument is a "letter" (and not digit or symbol etc)

Comment: Thanks, couldn't figure it out! :)